# PDO prepared statements with bit fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I experience an issue when working with PDO prepared statements and `bit` data types

When retrieving the result from the DB with PDO prepared statement an empty result set is returnd, but the correct results are returned if the query is done by a normal sql query

If the field `is_demo` in the where clause is omitted it works as it should!?

## DB table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_admin` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_demo` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varbinary(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `is_admin` (`is_admin`),
  KEY `is_demo` (`is_demo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

## PDO prepared statement

```
$sql = "SELECT id,client_id,is_admin,is_demo\n"
    ."FROM user\n"
    ."WHERE is_demo=? && client_id=? && name=? && pass=?\n"
    ."ORDER BY name";
$fields = [
    0,
    500,
    'test',
    123
];
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($fields);
```

## Return

```
PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT id,client_id,is_admin,is_demo
FROM user
WHERE is_demo=? && client_id=? && name=? && pass=?
ORDER BY name
)
```

No rows returned

## Ordinary query

```
SELECT id, client_id, is_admin, is_demo
FROM user
WHERE is_demo=0 && client_id=500 && name='test' && pass=123
ORDER BY name
```

## Return

Returns the correct number of rows

Comment: Tip: for multi-line string assignment, use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s. They're far easier to read, and you don't have to embed `\n` line breaks and worry about escaping quotes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540483/pdostatement-mysql-inserting-value-0-into-a-bit1-field-results-in-1-written

Comment: @rambo, add an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem `\n` can not be in query

```
$sql = "SELECT id,client_id,is_admin,is_demo\n"
."FROM user\n"
."WHERE is_demo=? && client_id=? && name=? && pass=?\n"
."ORDER BY name";
```

Comment: it works fine for all other queries.. if the `is_demo` line in the where clause is omitted it works

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can transform the string value "0" to bit writing the code like this with "B" before the string:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,client_id,is_admin,is_demo\n"
    ."FROM user\n"
    ."WHERE is_demo=B? && client_id=? && name=? && pass=?\n"
    ."ORDER BY name";
$fields = [
    '0', 
    500,
    'test',
    123
];
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($fields);
```