# BIT columns all “1” after a phpMyAdmin export/import

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, bit

I have to import data from a MySQL database using phpMyAdmin.

I have exported my database from my local machine using phpMyAdmin. After that I imported the script file to my host. All of data in the columns that is BIT type are changed to '1'. Hosting database version is 5.5.27.

Is it a phpMyAdmin problem, or MySQL version problem? How can I fix this?

Please find below the database content while doing export

```
`-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 24, 2013 at 12:50 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.27
-- PHP Version: 5.4.7

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `bitTest`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bitTest` (
  `textName` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `bitValue` bit(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bitTest`
--

INSERT INTO `bitTest` (`textName`, `bitValue`) VALUES
('False', '0'),
('True', '1');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;`
```

Comment: same issue as this guy here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540483/pdostatement-mysql-inserting-value-0-into-a-bit1-field-results-in-1-written