# PHP PDO bindParam() and MySQL BIT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update data in a table with a BIT type value in it, like the following :

```
// $show_contact is either '1' or '0'
$query->bindValue(':scontact', $show_contact, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

The problem is, it never changes the value, it remains '1' as set on PHPMyAdmin. I tried different `PDO::PARAM_` types without success, everything else is working.

**edit** full script

```
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = :password, address = :address, postal = :postal, city = :city, contact = :contact, show_contact = :scontact WHERE id = :id";

        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        $query->bindValue(':id', $user->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':password', md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':postal', $postal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':contact', $contact, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':scontact', $show_contact, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
```

Comment: maybe you send it as string `'1'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDOstatement (MySQL): inserting value 0 into a bit(1) field results in 1 written in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540483/pdostatement-mysql-inserting-value-0-into-a-bit1-field-results-in-1-written)

Comment: and btw. you should use sha-256 instead of md5 http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` did the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDO has a bit of a bug where any parameter passed to a query, even when specifically given as PDO::PARAM_INT is treated as a string and enclosed with quotes. ***[READ THIS](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639)***

The only way to tackle it is to try the following:

```
$show_contact = (int)$show_contact;
$query->bindValue(':scontact', $show_contact, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: I was already casting it to integer, but the result was the same.

Comment: I was facing the same problem but casting the variable again to INT, before binding, did the job for me.

Comment: It worked, but I had to `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` as mentioned in another post, it was causing the value to be treated as string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the BIT type is mapped to PDO's `PARAM_BOOL`. Try using it with strictly boolean input.

```
$show_contact = (bool) $show_contact; // '0' => FALSE, '1' => TRUE
$query->bindValue(':scontact', $show_contact, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Comment: You mean cast the input value to boolean?

Comment: Yes, like `$query->bindValue(':scontact', (bool)$show_contact, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);`

Comment: Thank you, this answer did it! I added source code for others to see.