# Insert BIT value in MySQL using PDO Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

How do I insert a BIT value in MySQL using a PDO Prepared Statement?  Below is what I tried and my results.

```
<?php
function testIt($value)
{
    $sql='INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES(?,?)';
    $stmt=db::db()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(0,$value));
    $id=db::db()->lastInsertId();

    $sql='SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='.$id;
    $stmt=db::db()->query($sql);
    $rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo("Test for {$value} returns id {$rs['id']} and data {$rs['data']}<br>");
}

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('../../ayb_private/dbase.php');

$sql='CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, data BIT(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 00000000, PRIMARY KEY (id) )';
$stmt=db::db()->exec($sql);

testIt('b"01010101"');
testIt('b01010101');
testIt('01010101');
testIt(0x55);
testIt("b'01010101'");
?>
```

RESULTS:

```
Test for b"01010101" returns id 1 and data 255
Test for b01010101 returns id 2 and data 255
Test for 01010101 returns id 3 and data 255
Test for 85 returns id 4 and data 255
Test for b'01010101' returns id 5 and data 255
```

Comment: Does `testIt(0x55)` work?

Comment: @Barmar `Test for 85 returns id 4 and data 255`

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can get insight from these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pdo+prepare+title%3Abit

Comment: According to the mysql docs, the bit literal format is `b'01010101'` - have you tried that?

Comment: @SamDufel  Without a prepared statement, `db::db()->exec("INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES(0,b'01010101')");` works.  I tried changing `'b"01010101"'` to `"b'01010101'"`, but no change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not near a terminal to check, but I believe you have to type bind it to INT and send it in as an INT, not as "b010101" (or whatever):

```
$sql='INSERT INTO test(id,data) VALUES(:id,:bit)';
$stmt=db::db()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('id', null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
$stmt->bindValue('bit', (int)$value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Quick check on Google brought up this [similar previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542145/2908724).

Comment: Using your solution and `testIt(0x55);` seems to work.  Instead of binding, maybe just convert the binary value using PHP might work?

Comment: This post answers the question, but does provide the answer I wanted to hear.  It appears that PDO doesn't work very well with BIT values.  Since these values are not user-provided, I suppose I could manually add them to my query.  Or maybe ditch BIT type all together and use `TINYINT(1)`.  Thoughts?

Comment: @user1032531 As I recall, you can't send a bit through PDO to MySQL: you'll at best always be sending an integer and, even then, if you don't explicitly tell PDO to use an integer, it sends as a string.  If your use case is storing bit fields in a database, then `bindValue` the integer representation and it works (like above).  If though your use case is selecting by bit field from a known set of possible bit fields, just encode them directly in your query.

Comment: My application is a basic permission system.  I have a 6 bit value representing user_read/user_write/group_read/group_write/public_read/public_write.  My WHERE clause will check if certain bits of the field are set.  It seems like I can do this with a TINYINT.  Agree? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, `TINYINT` keeps it simple and better maps to what you're doing: bit *masking*.  `BIT` is best when you have a wide range of bit values (0 to 2**63-1) and you absolutely care about storage consumption.  [Check out this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/).

Comment: Just tested with `TINYINT`, and I get the functionality I need.  I will go that way.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user1032531 - the mysql `SET` data type might work better for you - it maps internally into mysql as a bitmask check, but gives you access to it via string identifiers.