# PDO MySql has hard time inserting bit values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I cannot insert 1 or 0 into my bit column.

```
$executes=[1];
$prepare=$connection->prepare('insert into TABLE(BITVALUE) values(?)');
$prepare->execute($executes);
```

Will spit out an error of:

```
STRING DATA, RIGHT TRUNCATED: 1406 DATA TOO LONG FOR COLUMN
```

But its clearly an INT data type. Does execute change my datatype?

Comment: No, can you please post `EXPLAIN \`TABLE\`;` (guessing "TABLE" isn't your table name?

Comment: No, TABLE is just a representation of my table name. It's just an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDOstatement (MySQL): inserting value 0 into a bit(1) field results in 1 written in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540483/pdostatement-mysql-inserting-value-0-into-a-bit1-field-results-in-1-written)