# PDO issue with bit fields

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to execute insert in table with bit fields, but as result all fields are filled as 1 by default. Do not understand where my mistake or this is some specific in PDO.

Example of preapred query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (is_hidden, is_on_net, is_off_net, is_international)
VALUES (:is_hidden, :is_on_net, :is_off_net, :is_international)

[is_hidden] => 0
[is_on_net] => 1
[is_off_net] => 0
[is_international] => 0


$this->db->preparedQuery($query, $data);

public function preparedQuery($query, $params)
{
    try
    {
        $this->checkConnection();
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        
        if (!$stmt->execute($params))
        {
            $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, __FUNCTION__, $this->logLevel, 1, 'Failed to execute prepared query! ' . $this->pdo->errorInfo()[2] . ', query: ' . $query . ', params: ' . json_encode($params));
            
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, __FUNCTION__, $this->logLevel, 1, 'Failed to execute prepared query! ' . $e->getMessage() . ', query: ' . $query . ', params: ' . json_encode($params));
        
        return false;
    }
    
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the _real_ PHP code which sets up the query and params. You've just shown us some pseudo-code. And also a `var_dump()` of the parameters so we can see their values and datatype. Thx.

Comment: I see from this topic is the problem in PDO with bit fields for prepared query, and need to change to tinyint - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540483/pdostatement-mysql-inserting-value-0-into-a-bit1-field-results-in-1-written

Comment: Ah, OK. So you're going to change to `TINYINT(1)`?

Comment: Yes already changed. It works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved with changing data field to `tinyint`, because there are some problems with bit fields in PDO.

Same question: [PDOstatement (MySQL): inserting value 0 into a bit(1) field results in 1 written in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540483/pdostatement-mysql-inserting-value-0-into-a-bit1-field-results-in-1-written)